# How to solve Stream encountered HTTP error 403 in Python?

Tags: python, http, http-status-code-403

I am trying to create a Stream Listener in tweepy to listen for incoming Tweets on a specific page / account.

I followed all the guidelines so far: I have elevated access for the Twitter API, I have fresh regenerated keys with read/write/DM checks, OAuth 1.0a turned on, triple checked the keys used in the script... and with all of those... still 403 Error.

```
 class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.id)
        if not status.text.startswith("RT ") and status.in_reply_to_screen_name is None:
            print('https://twitter.com/' + username + "/status/" + str(status.id))


# create stream and filter on a searchterm
twitterListener = MyStreamListener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
twitterListener.filter(track=['#HashTag'], threaded=True)
```

Where can this error be coming from? I am going mad trying to solve it... Everything should be in place...

But I keep getting this...

Stream encountered HTTP error: 403
Stream encountered HTTP error: 403
Stream encountered HTTP error: 403
Stream encountered HTTP error: 403

Thanks!

Comment: Hey i too have the same problem, no matter how many times i changed the api tokens and access tokens the error wont go at all

Comment: Are you using a Twitter Developer App created on or after 2022-04-29?

Comment: did you ever find any solution ??

Comment: Not any solution so far... I went with while True instead of a Listener :))) Not the best approach but I couldn't find the source of the error...

Comment: Again, are you using a Twitter Developer App created on or after 2022-04-29?

Comment: @Harmon758after! Sorry for late answer.